# Creating a transparent inactive button - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Im currently trying to create a button for a game menu, an image is being used over the top of said button, which i want to be transparent as the background is supposed to be seen through the back of the image(png with transparent background). Is there anyway for me to create this button with a transparent in-active state within pygame?

edit: such as a colour code for a transparent colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that removing the `draw` line for a button (rectangle) when it is inactive would fix this.

Original code:

```
def button(x, y, width, height, active_color, action = None):
cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x,y,width,height))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
        print("reached")
        if action == "quit":
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif action == "instructions":
            print("instructions")
        elif action == "credits":
            print("credits")
        elif  action == "warrior":
            print("warrior")
        elif action == "archer":
            print("archer")
        elif action == "mage":
            print("mage")
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (x,y,width,height))
```

Correct code:

```
def button(x, y, width, height, active_color, action = None):
cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x,y,width,height))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
        print("reached")
        if action == "quit":
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif action == "instructions":
            print("instructions")
        elif action == "credits":
            print("credits")
        elif  action == "warrior":
            print("warrior")
        elif action == "archer":
            print("archer")
        elif action == "mage":
            print("mage")
else:
    pass
```

Note that the `else` isn't even necessary in the end, and could be removed. I just left it to show where I had changed the code.